# Prove that $A+B+I$ is invertible given two conditions on the square matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces

> Let $p$ be a prime. Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices with complex coefficients so that $AB=BA$ and $A^{p-1} = B^p = I$, the identity matrix. Prove that $A+B+I$ is invertible.

Suppose $(A+B+I)v = 0$ for some vector v. Equivalently, $Av = -(B+I)v$. It suffices to show that $v=0$. I think it could be useful to find polynomials f and g so that $f(A) v = g(B)v=0$. Some possibly useful polynomials to consider might be $x^p, x^{p-1}, x^{p-1}-1, (x+1)^{p-1}-1, x^p-1$. Clearly, if we let f and g be the last two polynomials respectively, then they work. The commutativity of the matrices A and B shows that $(A+B)^{p-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} {p-1\choose k} A^k B^{p-1-k}.$ Also, the minimal polynomials of A and B divide f and g respectively. I was thinking of making use of the fact that p is prime somehow, but this problem doesn't seem closely related to elementary number theory and so theorems like Fermat's little theorem don't seem useful for this problem. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: do you understand that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable?